# List View Does not show more than 10 Item

Tags: android

I am trying to display some data in a list view.
Each row contains an image , textview and a checkbox.
I have created my own Adapter class : MyAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter.
When the length of the array string passed to the adapter exceeds 10 the list does not show at all.

This is how I am setting the adapter :

```
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textView1, phonecontacts));
```

And this is my adapter class :

```
 private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, String[] phonecontacts) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, phonecontacts);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);//layout , paremt , false
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            name.setText(phonecontacts[position]);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultcontact);
            return row;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If your problem is a crash because of a memory leak, then you should reuse your row at your adapter.

Comment: Use viewholder it is better. does your app crash

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayAdapter maximum size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821270/arrayadapter-maximum-size)

Comment: Thank you for your solutions , I Think it was a crash because of memory leak , i didnt change anything in my code , i restarted the phone and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  your `getView` method to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);//layout , paremt , false            
    }

    row = convertView;

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    name.setText(phonecontacts[position]);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultcontact);

    return row;
}
```

It is very dangerous to inflate a new row at every time. It is going to cause a crash because of a memory leak. Try to reuse the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Probabbly a memory issue, try using as described here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html .

At your place I would use phone contacts as ArrayList not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating a view each time getView() gets called

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);//layout , paremt , false
    ...
}
```

add a check whether the view exists or not and inflate if false

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    ....
}
```